What would happen to the overall climate in New England if the warm Jet Stream crossing the United States moved from its course further south?
I'm working on a post-apocalyptic story that will have various climate-related disasters across the United States, significantly contributing to the struggles of the people still managing to survive there. I was thinking that removing that influx of warm air would create some significant challenges, but I'm not sure what direction. I would imagine the temperatures would go down broadly, and this would have a significant impact on precipitation, but in all my research, I can't quite seem to nail down what we could expect the shift in the climate there to be.

The jet streams do not have anything like a fixed course. They are meandering and wander about very widely, moving thousands of miles north or south as they please. One of the main tasks of weather balloons is to find out where the jet stream is on any given day, because knowing where it is is very important in order to know how weather fronts will move for the purpose of weather forecast, and very important for air travel, because aircraft flying west to east want to fly with the jet stream, and aircraft flying east to west want to be nowhere near it.

@AlexP Not nessacarily. They do move around a decent bit, but the main ones remain in (relatively) fixed locations. A good example is the Gulf Stream, which sends warm air to much of Europe.

@Bubbles: The Gulf Stream is an ocean current. The question is about the jet streams which are high altitude winds. They literally meander over thousands of miles north or south of their supposed "average" place. The northern polar jet stream, which I believe to be the object of the question, is supposed to blow on the average somewhere around 60 degress north, but in reality it just about never follows a strict circle and you can quite often find it meandering at 40 degrees north, 1,200 miles south of its supposed "average" place.

@AlexP, I know I can't ask additional questions, but would it be a fair characterization to say that the answer to this question is probably, "You actually want to know about what affect a massive change to the ocean current called the Gulf Stream's position would have"?

The question asks about the jet stream(s), which are high altitude winds, that is, flows of air. The Gulf Stream is an ocean current, a flow of water. There is no relationship between the jet stream(s) and the Gulf Stream. And anyway, while the southern parts of the New England coast (= Connecticut and Rhode Island) do receive some small influence from the Gulf Stream, the northern parts of the New England coast (= Maine and Massachusetts) are under the strong influence of the cold Labrador current.

I hope you won't take this the wrong way, but I actually do know the content of my own question, and I understand that there are differences between ocean and air currents. I also am not a climate scientist, which was why I was asking the question about climate effects. It would seem that the answer to my question is a pretty simple "no," which is fine. What I was trying to say is that I want to create a significant climate shift in New England and thought air stream changes would cause that; I wondered, then, if Gulf Stream changes would be able to create that change.

There are two jet streams that cross North America. These migrate naturally based on the season and may have huge swings between north and south over the continent. https://www.noaa.gov/jetstream/global/jet-stream We are already having the described movement of the jet stream.
The position of the jet stream affects where weather systems go as they cross the continent. That means that some places will get less rain than others.
The current crop of storms affecting the middle of the country and the east coast is driven more from the warm water in the Gulf of Mexico. The jet stream is mostly west to east. Moist air flows up from the Gulf of Mexico at a lower altitude and slower speed. There is a high pressure over Bermuda that helps drive air north. Winds at lower altitudes can reach 60 mph. That blowing for 24 hours will move moisture 1440 miles north (all the way from Houston to North Dakota). The interaction of the low-level moisture with the jet stream determines how severe the weather gets.
The challenges would be how much more variable the weather will be. Farmers want something of consistency to weather. When instead of dry weather to plant, they get soaking rains for days, that will prevent planting crops that year. Or if they want rain, they might get drought for years. Just before harvest, they might get a huge hailstorm destroying it all. More floods, more droughts, more severe storms. In short, it will put the food production at much higher risk.

Would it be fair to say, then, that there couldn't be a change of significant magnitude and length that could alter the climate for the New England region permanently? It seems that the position is already pretty variable...

@Amocito The one thing we can say from geological studies is that the climate varies a lot over time. The jet stream varies day by day. One day, it can dip from Montana to Texas and the next be mostly straight across the country. You need to find another mechanism for changing New England climate. (See the year without a summer.)
